# Jquery: help to get values from data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup

```
<a href='#' id="remove_user_from_group" data-user-id="a9a4ae36-c6cd-11e1-9565-910084adb773" data-group-id="e4d66f80-d046-11e1-89b6-16f96811a1bd">x</a>
```

And I want to get the data from `user-id` and `group-id`.

For now, I have tried:

```
$this = $(this);
$("#remove_user_from_group").live('click', function() {
    var userid = $this.data('user-id');
    var groupid = $this.data('group-id');
    alert(userid);
    alert(groupid);
});
```

which pops me 2 alerts with `undefined` values.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Put `$this = $(this);` inside your click function. Also as an aside, `live()` has been deprecated in favor of `on()`.

Comment: @j08691 thanks! didn't know about the deprecation, thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `$this = $(this);` inside your click function. Or, change the function to just:

```
$("#remove_user_from_group").live('click', function() {
    var userid = $(this).data('user-id');
    var groupid = $(this).data('group-id');
    alert(userid);
    alert(groupid);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/stqRj/)** and **[jsFiddle example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jR2ju/)**

Also as an aside, [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated in favor of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the object in the function to a Jquery Object by changing `$(this)` instead of `$this` on line 3 and 4